# Have hidden implementation of functions in Swift like in the documentation?

Tags: swift, xcode, libraries

I am building a rather large library and I think it would be a lot cleaner if I could have the implementation for my methods and such hidden. For example, when you view the in-code documentation for standard Swift types, such as `UInt64`, you see things like:[image]

With the actual implementation of the methods hidden, and only the declarations and headers shown. How can I do this with my own library?

Comment: Write a framework / module. That is what Swift is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to distribute your library as a precompiled binary, in which case only the public headers + documentation will be visible for consumers of your library.

For more information, you can watch the WWDC2019 video of about [Binary frameworks in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/).

Comment: I was making the "Swift Package" that Xcode lets you make. Am I able to do it with this as well?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to create a binary framework with Xcode 11

Comment: @SylvanM. The whole _point_ of a package is that it is open source. (Well, not the _whole_ point; there's also the dependency management.) If you didn't want the source to be exposed, you shouldn't have elected to make a package.

Comment: @matt, ok that makes sense, I guess I just thought it would look cleaner if I could have implementations in a different file. Thanks, though.

Comment: @SylvanM. In general that's not how Swift works. Objective-C by convention divides into interface and implementation files; Swift doesn't, in the sense that you can't say e.g. `func ...` in one file but have the body of that function declared elsewhere. So the only way to hide the implementation is to have a binary so that there is no source code visible and it is up to you to document the interface.

Comment: @matt, You're right, I guess I just need to get used to Swift and unlearn some C habits.

Comment: @SylvanM. I would strongly recommend that you not do what you’re asking to do. Stick with the package. Keep your code open. Organize it neatly into many files if needed, but don’t hide your code in a binary. You won’t gain acceptance that way. It’s an open source world.

Comment: @matt, I definitely agree. I even often argue with my CS teacher about the importance of open source code (they for some reason hate it) and I fully intend for my library to be open sourced. I only wanted to put the implementation in another file for neatness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut in Xcode to show only the interface: Control+Command+Up Arrow, but it is a little slow and doesn't hide the internal methods that not useful for the usage of the code (since only public and open interface in Swift Package can be used by outside module).